# webapp security by id signing

Tags: security

Suppose I write a web application that stores a lot of information in its database that should only be accessible to users with privileges.  A post, for example, may only be readable by its author.  For the sake of the example, suppose that each word in the post is assigned an id and must also be checked to see if the user actually has permission to use that word.  When transmitting ajax requests to the server, the ids must all be sent to the server for the request (details of why aren't important).  For security, I want to verify that the user is authorized to use each word to foil an attacker that is fabricating his own ajax request.  I could query the SQL database for each word to check authorization which will probably involve one or more joins.  This results in 100s of queries.  I would like to avoid querying so much.  (In my specific implementation, I'm not using posts and words, but I will need to handle ~100 database ids in some requests.)

I came up with a possible solution and I would like some feedback.  Instead of transmitting integers as ids to the web application, it encodes the id in a signed-id-placeholder.  The signature works by assigning every session a secret key that is stored in the session table and not send to the client.  To encode an id, the id, id type ('user_id', etc.), and the secret key are appended together and piped through a hash algorithm. A fixed length portion of this resulting hash is appended to the unencoded id and then sent to the client.  To reduce its length, it's also encoded with 0-9,A-Z,a-z or base-62.  The result is that the actual id is in clear-text (though slightly masked by the different base) and a signature is appended to it.  This way, changing the id will invalidate the signature and the server will not honor the request.  In my current implementation, I'm using a signature length of 56 bits for about 7.2x10^16 possible signatures.

What are you reactions to this plan? Overkill? Flawed? Is there an accepted, better solution?

Here is a code snipet in php of the signing function (excuse the use of magic numbers, this is a testing implementation):

```
public function signDbId( $id, $kind )
{
  $id_seg = base62( $id );
  $hash = md5( $id_seg . $kind . $this->session_key );
  $signed = '';
  for ( $i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i )
  {
    $signed .= base62( intval( substr( $hash, $i*8, 7 ), 16 ), 5 );
    // pad to 5 chars
  }
  return $signed . $id_seg;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the authorization problem and the hundreds of queries problem are necessarily related. For a given request, I would want to first authorize the identity of the user (using a CSRF token) and then check to see whether that user has permissions to do the thing she asked to do (using some sort of internal permissions module).

Comment: The user is logged in. I check that with a secured session cookie.  No problem.  User wants to modify properties of 100 items.  I want to make sure that he isn't guessing the ids of his neighbors items in a fabricated request.  I can use a query for each one or sign the ids to make it really hard to guess a neighboring id.  That's my thought process.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a CSRF Token (Cross site request forgery), it is a common practice, but I think you are making it a bit more complicated than it needs to be.

The CSRF token can just be randomly generated and stored in your database.

**EDIT**

After re-reading your question, I realize that a typical CSRF token wouldn't solve the problem of needing to execute many queries, but I think the need to execute hundreds of queries is a symptom of a bad application design.

Comment: This is the kind of request I want: apply x label to these 124 emails.  I want to verify the ids of each email to make sure that the user actually owns them.  I'm not explicitly trying to prevent CSRF, but trying to prevent user A from editing (or gaining access to) user B's data without permission.

Comment: @Jonathan Swinney, once you have authenticated the user, why would that require more than one query, what is wrong with `SELECT email FROM WHERE user_id = X`?

Comment: I need to write a query like this: INSERT INTO email_labels (email_id,label_id) VALUES( ...